# How to save to a bitmap in MFC C++ application?

Tags: c++, mfc, bmp

I am just starting with MFC so please be tolerant ;).
I have wrote (it was mostly generated to be honest) a simple application which should do the Paint chores: drawing lines, rectangulars, ellipses, changing a color of object to be drawn etc.

I need to save what has been drawn on the screen into a bmp file. Any ideas how can I achieve this ?

I do not know if that's relevant but I am drawing objects on the screen without the use of any CBitmaps  or things like that. Here is a part of code responsible for drawing :

```
CPaintDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
Anchor.x=point.x;
Anchor.y=point.y;
OldPoint.x=Anchor.x;
OldPoint.y=Anchor.y;
if(pDoc->shapeCount>=MAX_SHAPES) return;
pDoc->shapeCount++;

if(bFreehand)
    {
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1] = new Shape;
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->shape = ePoint;
    }
if(bLine)
    {
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1] = new CLine;
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->shape = eLine;
    }
if(bRectangle)
    {
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1] = new CRectangle;
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->shape = eRectangle;
    }
if(bEllipse)
    {
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1] = new CEllipse;
    pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->shape=eEllipse;
    }
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->x=point.x;
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->y=point.y;
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->x2=point.x;
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->y2=point.y;
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->Pen=CurrentPen;
pDoc->m_shape[pDoc->shapeCount-1]->Brush=CurrentBrush;
bButtonDown=true;
SetCapture();
```

I have found this way to do it but I don't know how to obtain screen width and height to fill it in the CreateBitmap parameter's list

```
        CBitmap *bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateBitmap(desktopW, desktopH, 1, 32, rgbData);
    CImage image;
    image.Attach(bitmap);
    image.Save(_T("C:\\test.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateBitmap` call only requires the desktop width and height if the image you wish to save is actually the entire size of the screen.  If that's indeed your intent, you can use `CWnd::GetDesktopWindow()` to get a `CWnd` object that you can query for its width and height:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkxb36k8(v=VS.80).aspx

That gets dodgy in general...if for no other reason than multi-monitor scenarios...so I'd recommend against it unless you really feel like writing a screen capture app.

What you probably want to do isn't to take a full screen shot, but just save the contents of your program's window.  Typically you'd do this by breaking out the drawing logic of your program so that in the paint method you call a helper function that is written to take a `CDC` device context.  Then you can either call that function on the window-based DC you get in the paint call or on a DC you create from the bitmap to do your save.  Note that you can use a `CBitmap` in `CDC::SelectObject`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/432f18e2(v=VS.71).aspx

*(Though let me pitch you on not using MFC.  Try [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)) instead.  Way better.)*

Comment: Thanks for answer. First of all: how can I query CWnd for width and height. Secondly is there a way where I can get the CDC device context out of *View.cpp file ? I am getting a bit confused with MFC being message handling instead of standard 'int main()' type of thing.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the acronym RTFM or what it means, then you should *definitely* use a more modern technology!  Anyone who remembers MFC isn't on StackOverflow answering questions about it recreationally.  :)  If you have a CWnd and want a size from the CWnd, your plumbing is GetClientRect.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: As for now I see that I suold definately use QT next time :( but now I have to hand in this project (even though not complete) today... and yea... RTFM but no time for that now. Thanks for the response anyway.